# Why use private blockchain for logistics? Like Walmart does

Tags: private-blockchain, hyperledger

Walmart uses blockchain to track their products origins https://www.hyperledger.org/learn/publications/walmart-case-study

> Using blockchain and storing the information digitally, a supplier
> could theoretically see which farms are infected and quickly stop the
> supply to restaurants and consumers

I find blockchain one of the least suitable technologies to use for this task. It slower than traditional DB, developers with such expertise are harder to find and they even needed IBM to develop something on top of Hyperledger solution.

What am I missing? Why not use NoSQL(for example, Cassandra which can also be immutable)? D